# SSRS 2008 Excel Currency Cell Format

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm using SSRS 2008 and I have a financial report. I would like the dollar amounts in my table to be in currency or number format when exported to Excel. Currently they end up being text.

I have trying a few things to see if its even possible. I removed the table header, didn't use the $ sign, and converted the field to decimal, but nothing seemed to work. The data in Excel always seems to be format as text.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that instead of using a format **function** in the expression like:

```
=Format(myvar.value, "C")
```

Its better to not to use an expression and just change the **Text Box Properties** on that field. For example, I'd leave the field as:

```
 =myvar.value
```

Then I would right click on the field, go to Text Box Properties, Number Sub Category/Tab, and select currency.

When doing this the results in Excel are a custom number format vs a text format.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the Format string "C" but the export to excel is really a text rendering - it does not hold Excel specific attributes/qualities.