# How can I prevent the "Number Stored as Text" err indicators from displaying in an Excel sheet exported from an SSRS report?

Tags: excel, reporting-services, export-to-excel, number-formatting, rdl

I get the green triangle error messages on all the numeric values on my report:

[image]

These are visible if the Excel user has checked "Enable Background Error Checking" in the Formulas tab on the Excel Options dialog; the err msg that displays is:

[image]

It's true that the ItemCode and PriceWeek (shown with a data range as a column heading, in this case 5/1 to 5/7) fields are Strings, but the Variance field, which is also green flagged as problematic, is a Decimal:

```
<Field Name="ItemCode">
  <DataField>ItemCode</DataField>
  <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
</Field>
<Field Name="PriceWeek">
  <DataField>PriceWeek</DataField>
  <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
</Field>
<Field Name="Variance">
  <DataField>Variance</DataField>
  <rd:TypeName>System.Decimal</rd:TypeName>
</Field>
```

So what can I do to solve the problem if even Decimal values are seen as Strings masquerading as Numbers. The data is what it is (Strings, for the most part) so is there a way to cast them all as the type of Number SSRS-to-Excel needs to prevent the green triangle error indicators?

And yes, the fact that two of my column headers (they should read "05/01/2016 to 05/07/2016" to the right of "Member" and "05/08/2016 to 05/14/2016" to the right of "Variance") are dropping through the bottom of the header row (in the exported Excel sheet only - not on the Preview tab or when exported as a PDF) is already a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311947/how-can-i-prevent-two-of-my-column-headings-from-dropping-through-to-the-next-ro).

### UPDATE

Here are the only two places in the rdl/xml file where "$" is encountered (where the string values are being cosmetically changed to "currencty" values:

```
 . . .
     <Value>=IIF( (Fields!regionorder.Value=1000), "", IIF((Fields!Price.Value=""),"$0.00","$"+Fields!Price.Value))</Value>
 </Textbox>

 <Textbox Name="Variance">
    . . .                                                                                          
    <Format>$#######0.00</Format>
    . . .
```

Comment: I am gathering by the code, you are not using excel VBA to import the data to excel.  is the error on your variance numbers the same as that ast the column beside it, or is the error that the variance column is not the same format as adjacent cells.  While unsightly, these are only warnings and not actual errors.  is it possible to export your prices as decimals as well?  How did you get the formatting on variances to show as financial?

Comment: No, I'm not using VBA; this is generated from SSRS, then exported to Excel. All the code is in the rdl/xml file.

Comment: I can understand why Excel is making the flags,  It can see the strings as numbers which is prefers and knows they are in a format that will usually cause issues. Its also why your ITEM CODE is also flagged.  I can think of several ways around this inside of excel, but you ideally want to deal with this at the source. The best way is normally to pass numbers is as numbers. This is why I asked how you got your variance to format with $ out front (financial) when from you code it looks like you passed it as a decimal. If it was truly just a decimal excel would treat it as -1.02 instead of -$1.02

Comment: I know why it's doing it, too, but the data is the data (strings). I didn't do it, but there is code within the rdl/xml to add the $. That's just cosmetic, though - it still sees the value as potentially problematic because of the string/number mismatch.

Comment: if by adding the $ it turn the number from the decimal to a string I am clueless to your option without doing something inside excel.  If adding the $ was the rdl/xml way of adding formatting to the cell and then you have your way in for removing the green flags around your numbers.  That is why I earlier asked if the green flag was the same error message  for the variance as for the Priceweek.   So while yes the $ is cosmetic, I was hoping it may shed light on how things were being manipulated.

Comment: They want the "$" sign, so removing them is not a viable solution. It's easier for them to turn off the err checking. In fact, I couldn't see what they were talking about at first - I had to manually turn that on first. I'll add an update to show what's going on in the rdl/xml file.

Comment: I am not suggesting at all to remove the sign.  I was hoping that in the way the information is being passed they are also passed cell formatting.  IF, and that is a huge IF, this is just a matter of manipulating the cell formatting you are off to the races.  However if this is more like a CSV file with no formatting and just strings in the end after $ have been added, then I think you are SOL without going into excel itself and massaging the sheet.  HOPEFULLY someone else can prove me wrong and can come up with an option for you.

Comment: I did a little google search and found the following article which may be of use to you, or give you some ideas on [how to export your numbers to excel and not have them read as strings](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/507656/reporting-services-export-to-excel-issue-with-numbers-converting-as-text).  I also found [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136909/ssrs-2008-excel-currency-cell-format) which may help too.

Comment: now admittedly changing your numbers to financial format for excel will help for your prices and variance...it is not going to do squat for your account number!  As long at the account number does not have leading zero and is an integer, you should be OK.  Though someone in the first link said they had issues with excel displaying account numbers greater than 12 characters in length that had all numbers as being displayed in exponential format.  Their solution was to ensure their was at least one letter in the string.  As such I was wondering if a trailing/leading space would work the same.

Comment: Thanks; I czeched out that link, but the best hint I got from there led me to this observation: In the designer (Properties tab), I see that the Variance data textbox has as its Format property "$#######0.00" If there's a way to set format to show $ signs but also prevent the err msg, I'm all eyes

Comment: Make sure you check out the second link as well to the SO question.  it has a command line in there for formatting C2 property or something to that effect

Comment: How did you make out with the formatting your numbers as currency?  Did that second link work things out for you?

Comment: No, it makes no difference. I think it's because the source values are strings, and that I cannot change.